# How is uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast different from Thread.sleep?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-espresso

In [this video from Google I/O 2016](https://youtu.be/isihPOY2vS4?t=11m25s), Wojtek Kaliciński recommends using `uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast` instead of `Thread.sleep` in Espresso tests. Granted, the context is around Idling Resources, but what's the difference between the two and why is one better than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Espresso uses a queue to check if app is idle.

```
Thread.sleep(x) = //Waits x 
uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(x) // Waits x + more if app is still not idle
```

Now both of this are really bad approaches, that will result in some problems in production code.

1. Espresso can detect if app is idle if you are using AsyncTasks
   but in some scenarios it can't. So even when your app isn't idle,
   `uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(x)` will be skipped.
2. Using `IdlingResources` inside production code to specify when
   app is not idle is not a good solution. You shouldn't change
   production code to test your app and idling resources checks if app
   is idle with 5 second intervals which will cause lots of overhead in
   your tests. Assume you have 100 test cases where you will experience
   this interval, the overhead you will experience will be huge
3. Using `Thread.sleep(x)`by itself is obviously a bad idea. As your
   tests needs to be stable regardless of the speed of internet
   connection, phone etc you shouldn't be waiting a fixed amount of
   time. And you can't know how much time you need to wait when you
   request something from a server so `x` you decide will either be too
   big or too small.

The best solution is to check if the target view you have in your assertion/action exists and if not check the target view again after X seconds (where X is a small number like 200 millis). Also using `Thread.sleep()` worked better for me than using
    uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast() when my app was showing animations (even when animations were closed from testOptions  and phone settings)

Comment: I'm not sure if your solution of checking if the view exists every X seconds is the best, but it's what I've been doing as well. I agree that adding `IdlingResources` to production code smells bad.

Comment: Checking if the view exists every X seconds is what Selenium/Appium users refer to as an explicit wait

Reference to Selenium Code:


`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);`


`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(loginScreen)).click();`